# Reading image files serially from a folder in matlab

Tags: matlab

I tried to read .jpg files from a folder in matlab using dir command. But I am not getting them from the first image stored in the folder. Instead it started from 10th image. I want to know how to read the files serially starting from the beginning.

Comment: What matlab function are you using to "get" *.jpg from the folder?  I assume you want them sorted by name, or date, etc.  Which is it?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I am using dir command

Comment: Template = dir('IrisTemplates\*.jpg');                                 If I type  Template(1).name 

It gives the ans = template_10_1_1.jpg                                                    But I am expecting Template(1).name as template_1_1_1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain that if you are using a simple enough command, it will give you all files that are there. However, this may not seem to be the case because of this little line in the [description](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/dir.html):

```
Results appear in the order returned by the operating system.
```

This may mean, that you will first see files like 1, 100, 1000,1999 and only later a file with numer 2. Of course you can sort the results after you have collected them, and then process them in your desired order.

---

For completenes, one would like to have something like:

```
dir *.jpg
```

or if you want to be sure to catch everything that even remotely resembles .jpg:

```
dir *.*j*p*g*
```

Comment: I have a folder containing only image files(.jpg files) which are the results of some pre processing steps. Each file corresponds to an image. Now I want to access them one by one serially by name, for the further processing... and later I need to compare the results                        I use dir command to access the files. But the first structure element returned by the dir command is giving me 10th file instead of first file.